# Plotting histograms for all columns in a pandas data frame with data in string format and nan

Tags: python, matplotlib, exception, histogram, valueerror

I want to plot histograms for as many of the columns in my pandas data frame as possible.

All of the data in the data frame is in a **string** format to begin with. I've tried converting the data type before feeding it into `hist()`, along with an exception to be raised if a given column can't be converted.

I expect to see some histograms in the output. I only get my error message for when a plot can't be generated `This column can not be represented as a histogram` and `<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>`.

Thanks for any help!

```
# PACKAGES 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# DATA
data = {'col1': ['id345', 'id873', 'id972', 'id472', 'id930'],
        'col2': ['1.0', '0.0', '1.0', '0.0', np.nan],
        'col3': ['0.281', '0.380', '0.240', '0.260', '0.222'],
        'col4': ['0.17', '0.184', '0', '0.22', np.nan],
        'col5': ['1', '1', '0', np.nan, '0']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])


# PLOTS 
for col in df:   
    try:      
        plt.figure()
        df.hist([int(col)])

    except ValueError:
        print('This column can not be represented as a histogram')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few problems in your code:

- `int(col)` is wrongly used.
- `break` will stop your program as soon as any column which cannot be converted to numeric is encountered.
- `plt.figure()` is redundant because `df.hist()` creates its own figure

---

```
for col in df.columns: 
    try:      
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col]) 
        df.hist(column=col)
    except ValueError:
        print('This column can not be represented as a histogram')
```

Comment: Using the toy dataset and your code, I don't get any histograms in my output, just the error message. I don't understand why.